# Check if a NSDate object is in the past

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I want to check if an `NSDate` object I have is in the past or now (if it's not in the future).

I've tried this but it don't working:

```
-(void)checkIfMuted
{
    NSDate *muteOverDate=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"muteOverDate"];

    if ([muteOverDate timeIntervalSinceNow]<0.0) {
        self.muteEnabled=YES;
        return;
    }
    self.muteEnabled=NO;
    NSLog(@"%@\n%@",[[NSDate date] description],[muteOverDate description]);
}
```

**NSLog print:** `2016-02-10 14:55:19 +0000
2016-02-10 15:54:32 +0000`

Any idea why it's not working? Thanks!

Comment: So what isn't working?

Comment: The code you posted is fine. What's the issue? Your `if` statement will be true if `muteOverDate` is in the past. Given the log output, it is clear that `muteOverDate` is in the future (by nearly one hour).

Comment: @rmaddy You're right, I was wrong, I wanted to check if it was on the future :)

Comment: Then simply change the `<` to `>`.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`[NSDate compare:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1409748-compare?language=objc:):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
if ([now compare:muteOverDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    // muteOverDate is in the future
}
```

Comment: And if I want to check if it's in the future?

Comment: @FS.O `NSOrderedDescending`.

Comment: Thanks you very much!